# Websphere application Server cluster information

Tags: log4j, websphere, cluster-computing

I want to have a log file at each cluster level. Is there a way to retrieve cluster information at runtime. I am using Websphere Applciation Server

Comment: What cluster information do you want to fetch? Is it node name,cell name ? or do you want a common log file across the cluster?

Comment: Yes, logging the node name cell name etc in the logging file.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the [MBeans](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/public_html/mbeandocs/index.html)(Cluster, Server) provided by WebSphere.

Comment: I can't see cluster mbean in Jconsole, do i need to enable something? Another point is that , Can i get access to this Mbean object using java inside a server code? something like   MBeanServer mbServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();